# Iphone Statusbar message

Tags: iphone

Does anybody know how to show a color bar below the status bar (just like "return to call" when call minimized)? I need to do the same thing with my app, but my app is not a audio, music, VoIP, or location related app. I want to show to the user when app is minimized and the be able to just click the status and go back to app.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in iOS.  Sorry :(

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate on why it's impossible, or link to relevant documentation / discussions that confirm this?